# Android call back after layout rendering has completed?

Tags: android, callback, android-layout, android-service

How can i create/bind a service only after activity layout is rendered?

-- Update

I have two tabs (both as separate activities)on the main activity and the data used for tabs comes from Service. Right now i'm binding service inside `onCreate` method. Issue is that layout is not rendered till all the statements inside the `onCreate` gets finished. A blank screen is shown till the service get bind

Comment: Doesn't placing the code at the end of the `onCreate` do the thing?

Comment: @CommonsWare its because i have two tabs (both as separate activities)on the main activity and the data used for tabs comes from Service. Right now i'm binding service inside `onCreate` method. Issue is that layout is not rendered till all the statements inside the `onCreate` gets finished. A blank screen is shown till the service is  binded

Answer (score 2):

See [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html)

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/338479

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to create/bind the service at the end of your onCreate activity. If it must  absolutely bind/create at the very end of the process, you can add a boolean flag to your activity indicating whether you are already bound or have already created the service. You could then override onResume() as follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     if (!flag) {
          // Call code to bind/create the service.
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does not work, onResume does not guarantee that all views will be rendered by this point (e.g. ViewPager's fragments).