# Android equivalent to View.setTranslationX, but to adjust width?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have been spending hours unsuccessfully trying to adjust the width, height, and offset of a simple view in Android as the result of a button press. I have discovered that `setTranslationX` and `setTranslationY` always work; [the legacy method of setLayoutParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically) never works once the view is laid out initially. Calls to [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) and [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) similarly produce no results.

I have tried to setLayoutParams within the context of [posting a runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252382/updating-layoutparams-not-working), but this does nothing.

Because `setTranslationX` always works, I would just use that, but unfortunately there is no equivalent method like `setWidth` or `setHeight`.

As you can [see in the AOSP](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.3_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setTranslationX%28float%29), `setTranslationX` makes a call to `invalidateViewProperty`, which is a private method of `View`.

Is there an equivalent method to `setTranslationX` to adjust a view width or view margin, that presumably triggers invalidateViewProperty, and, by extension, works reliably?

EDIT

While in some situations, setLayoutParams may be expected to work after the initial layout, I am in a situation where setLayoutParams has no effect after the initial layout, but setTranslationX does. My setup is as follows:

- Running Android KitKat 4.4
- The view in question is MATCH_PARENT for both width, height
- The view in question is a child of a RelativeLayout
- The view in question is a View class with a simple solid-color background drawable

Here is the view:

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/border"
    android:background="@drawable/match_background_border_transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And here is the (non-working) code meant to dynamically alter its margins, but has no effect. Again, if I call setTranslationX, that always works.

```
    holder.toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageBorder.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) imageBorder.getLayoutParams();
                    p.leftMargin = 20;
                    p.rightMargin = 20;
                    p.topMargin = 20;
                    p.bottomMargin = 20;
                    imageBorder.setLayoutParams(p);
                    // imageBorder.setTranslationX does have an effect if I included it here
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try `view.layout`? I am not sure about `invalidateViewProperty` though

Comment: "the legacy method of setLayoutParams never works once the view is laid out initially" -- yes, it does.

Comment: Just added more info...just tried view.layout, it similarly had no effect...

Comment: Since we don't have all your code (e.g., the entire layout, the background image), it will be difficult for anyone to reproduce your findings. Try setting the margins to 20 initially, such as in your layout resource. If there is no effect, then the problem is not in *changing* the margins, but something else with regards to your layout, examining the margins, etc.

Comment: When I add margins in the XML, I do see an effect. Further, when I attempt to programmatically adjust LayoutParams for other views in the activity, it works. I must be hitting some kind of edge case in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have determined why setTranslationX was working, but setLayoutParams was not. My views were ultimately descendents of an [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). I was able to programmatically manipulate LayoutParams of the AdapterView and his siblings, but none of the AdapterView's descendents.

Additional research showed that this was a common Android question:

- [Margin on ListView items in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342461/margin-on-listview-items-in-android)
- [Why LinearLayout's margin is being ignored if used as ListView row view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278159/why-linearlayouts-margin-is-being-ignored-if-used-as-listview-row-view)

What was confusing was that this view was several levels deep; i.e., it went:

AdapterView -> FrameLayout -> RelativeLayout -> View

Anyhow, I was able to accomplish my programmatic layout goals by wrapping view in another view, and using [`setPadding`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).