# Android Google Maps SnapshotReadyCallback error

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to take a snapshot of my map:

```
SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bitmap = snapshot;
    }
};

map.snapshot(callback);
```

But it gives me this error:

> `width and height must be > 0`

Comment: try to give a height and width for bitmap object.

Comment: ok, but how should i do that ?

Comment: When do you call `GoogleMap.snapshot`?

Comment: at the end of the oncreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake of calling `snapshot` too early. Before all `View`s are layed out, they have a size of 0 by 0.

It's best to use this function on users action, e.g. in some `Button`'s `onClick`.

If you need it after the map is shown, you can try with `ViewTreeObserver`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/2183804.

Comment: ok i made it for in a button listener. if i run it it does nothing i think or i don't know where is it save the image...

Comment: @David Bitmap is returned to you via `Bitmap snapshot` parameter. The easiest way to check it worked, is e.g. setting background of the `Button` to this `Bitmap`.