# Android get and set layout width

Tags: java, android, xml, view, width

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="19" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutScrollContainer"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_background" >

           <
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want to get the width of the `HorizontalScrollView1` and set it to the `LinearLayout` (`layoutScrollContainer`)

This is my code in java but my app crashes , and I cant understand why . If you know how to do this with xml please tell me.

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById (R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    LinearLayout lrLayout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById (R.id.layoutScrollContainer);

    int  width = scrollView.getMeasuredWidth();
    lrLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

So... you haven't defined any ID for the Linear Layour. Check this:

```
 LinearLayout lrLayout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById (R.id.llayoutContainer1);
```

Just set the id for the linear layout :D

Comment: In fact everything is OK with Ids :D I will edit my question , sorry .. but the problem wasn't solved yet

Answer (score 0):

it crashes because the `LayoutParams` refers always to the Parent. In your case you are getting a `ClassCastException` because you are using the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came across it and have the answer.

It crashes probably because you doing this in `onCreate` - before the elements have been drawn or measured.

The best way to handle this is to use the `ViewTreeObserver` and after the layout is drawn, you can reset the width:

[How can you tell when a layout has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)

in particular, `scrollView.getMeasuredWidth()` won't work until the view is measured, after `onCreate`