# Getting 0 Value for both X and Y Coordinate of view(Imagebutton) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-imagebutton

I want to get X and Y Point of View(ImageButton).

When I try to find X and Y on Click event with below code I get proper X and Y coordinate for View.

```
    ImageButton imagebutton = findviewbyId(R.id.imagebutton);                       
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int[] posXY = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
            x = posXY[0];
            y = posXY[1];

            Log.d("X and Y Point", x + " " + y);        
        }
    });
```

But I want X and Y Co-ordinate before Click on view so I try to get X and Y with below code.

```
    ImageButton imagebutton = findviewbyId(R.id.imagebutton);                       
    int[] posXY = new int[2];
    imageButton.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
    x = posXY[0];
    y = posXY[1];

    Log.d("X and Y Point", x + " " + y);
```

But whenever I try to get X and Y with ClickListener I get X and Y as 0 and 0. So, I do not get Proper X and Y without ClickListener.
Could anyone help to solve out what is an actual issue, how can I get Proper X and Y without ClickListener?

Comment: *When* do you call `imageButton.getLocationOnScreen(posXY)`? If you call it before the actual layouting, it will always be `(0, 0)`. You need to wait for your layout to layout the views.

Comment: So, how can i get X and Y WIthout Click on it? is there any possible way?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972022/why-does-calling-getwidth-on-a-view-in-onresume-return-0) you can find a couple of solutions with some explanation and a helpful link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason the returned value is zero is because the ImageButton is not yet created if you call this method in 'onCreate()'.
You can use the ViewTreeObserver to get the position:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = imagebutton.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.imagebutton.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 

        int[] posXY = new int[2];

        imagebutton.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
        x = posXY[0];
        y = posXY[1];

        Log.d("X and Y Point", x + " " + y);  

    } 
});
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 4):

post() gets called after setContentView().

Method setContentView() ends up in callingViewGroup.addView() of the top view, andaddView() call always triggers requestLayout(). In turn, requestLayout() posts a task to the main thread to be executed later. This task will execute measure and layout on the view hierarchy. Now if you post another task it will be put into the queue afterlayout task and, as the result, always executed aftermeasure and layout happen. Thus you will always have valid sizes.

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21938380

```
button.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // get coordinates
    }
});
```

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto, Please help me out by explaining. I would like to understand.

Comment: this method will be called when the view is attached to the window, afaik.

Comment: But wouldn't you be running against the UI thread with no guarantees of starting after layout is drawn?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto dug deep, and found out this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21938380/2346980

Comment: @Evin1_ Please see the link.

Comment: Nice, so please add a short explanation to your answer to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Get the values on `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
    int[] posXY = new int[2];
    imagebutton.getLocationInWindow(posXY);
    int x = posXY[0];
    int y = posXY[1];

    Log.d("X and Y Point", x + " " + y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Implementing your logics in `onResume`.
- Using `ViewTreeObserver`.

  ```
  final ViewTreeObserver vto = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID).getViewTreeObserver(); 
  vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
      @Override 
      public void onGlobalLayout() { 
          vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  

          // Get X, Y of the ImageView here
      } 
  });
  ```

Comment: Check if vto is alive before removing.

Comment: @Keshav In this case, there's no need for that checking.

Comment: Let me check with this, By the way @Keshav what is vto?

Comment: @PranavPatel vto is the variable name.