# How to know whether the layout process is finished?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I need to call `requestLayout()` in my custome view, but I noticed

> This should not be called while the view hierarchy is currently in a layout pass ({@link #`isInLayout()`}.

So I deciede to use this code:

```
if(isInLayout()) {
    // request layout later
} else {
    requestLayout();
}
```

But the question is that I don't know how to request layout later, can I use `addOnLayoutChangeListener` ?

just like this:

```
addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to request a new layout after the layout pass that is in progress completes, take a look at [ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) and the `PreDraw()` method.

> **onPreDraw**
>
> boolean onPreDraw ()
>
> Callback method to be invoked when the view tree is about to be drawn. At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a frame. Clients can use this to adjust their scroll bounds or even to request a new layout before drawing occurs.

There are other methods that are part of the `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` interface that may also be what you are looking for.

---

You can also look at `post()` that is part of `View`. (See documentation [here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)). I believe that the `Runnable` that you post will be executed after the layout is completed on the view. That may be more of what you are looking for. Also take a look at the accepted answer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937224/does-posting-runnable-to-an-ui-thread-guarantee-that-layout-is-finished-when-it).

Comment: good answer! It seems the `post(runnable)` is the best way, and I'll use this method for `requestLayout()`. thanks a lot.