# How to avoid IllegalStateException When calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide, illegalstateexception

I have a horizontal recycler view called `imageRecyclerView` where each column consists solely of one `ImageView`. The adapter class for the recycler view is called `ImageAdapter`. The dataset of `imageRecyclerView`'s adapter is an `ArrayList` of strings that contain URLs. The `ArrayList` is called `currentImageURLs`.

Note - the purpose of all this code is to load images into `imageRecyclerView` one at a time.

In the `onBindViewHolder` method of my `ImageAdapter` class I have the following code. This code loads an image from the adapter's dataset into an `ImageView`. The code also waits until the image has been loaded into the `ImageView` before calling `recursivelyLoadURLs` to add a new item to the adapter's dataset.

```
    Glide.with(context)
            //items[[position] is a string that contains a URL 
            .load(items[position])
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    context.recursivelyLoadURLs()
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    context.recursivelyLoadURLs()
                    return false
                }

            })
            .apply(RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC))
            .into(holder.imageView)
```

The method `recursivelyLoadURLs` is in the parent Activity class. In essence, what this method does is

1] add another URL to `imageRecyclerView`'s adapter's dataset and

2] call `notifyDataSetChanged` so `imageRecyclerView` updates:

```
fun recursivelyLoadURLs() {


    if (currentImageURLs.size >= targetImageURLs.size) {
        return
    }

    currentImageURLs.add(targetImageURLs[currentImageURLs.size])

    //The code crashes on this line
    mainview.imageRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


}
```

However, the code is crashing with the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling` on the line labeled in the above code sample.

I suspect this is happening because `imageRecyclerView` is still computing a layout when `notifyDataSetChanged` is being called.

How can I delay calling `context.recursivelyLoadURLs` until the layout has finished being computed?

Or, how can I add a delay inside `recursivelyLoadURLs`, so that `notifyDataSetChanged` is only called once `imageRecyclerView` has finished computing its new layout?

Comment: Can I ask you what the purpose is of the code in `onBindViewHolder` is? Are you trying to make sure that image load one by one and not all together?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to only add another item to my recycler view, after the previous `ImageView`in the recycler view has finished loading an image. I updated my post with more explanation.

Comment: how about posting a runnable on the main thread with a delay?

Comment: @tompee I managed to fix the problem by adding a 1 millisecond delay using a coroutine- my problem with this solution is that it seems very inconsistent. For example, what if on a slower phone, a 1 millisecond delay isn't enough?

Comment: But coroutines run in parallel with the main thread, which introduces your concern. But I am talking about posting a runnable on the main thread. I am not sure the delay is even needed but just for good measure. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937224/does-posting-runnable-to-an-ui-thread-guarantee-that-layout-is-finished-when-it

Comment: I used your solution, and it worked. I'm going to post an answer with some code. Can you verify that what I am doing is correct?

Answer (score 3):

tompee has suggested posting a Runnable in order to guarantee the recycler view has layed out its children before running `notifyDataSetChanged`.

As such, I replaced `notifyDataSetChanged` with

```
    mainview.imageRecyclerView.post({
        mainview.imageRecyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation on [RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged)

> This event does not specify what about the data set has changed, forcing any observers to assume that all existing items and structure may no longer be valid. LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views.
>
> If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.

Here's some tips that might help *hope it helps :)

1. Try not to use the `notifyDataSetChanged()`, especially in your onBindViewHolder. Use `notifyItemChanged(position)` instead. It's much more efficient and cost less memory.
2. If you really need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, use it AFTER you are ready with ALL of your data (maybe have it when `currentImageURLs.size >= targetImageURLs.size`)

Comment: I can't use `notifyDataSetChanged` after all the URLs have been loaded because I want to load one URL at a time. Also, can I use `notifyItemChanged` after adding a new item to recycler view, I thought it was only used when modifying an existing item?

Comment: You can use `notifyItemInserted(position)` to notify when there's any insertion