# Map layout animationworking bad android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

So I am trying to make an animation, I have a Map and I want to make it move down to make place for a layout ot be shown. 
The animation works perfectly, the map moves down; and the layout is visible (the layout contains a button, textEdit and a textView). So my problem is that I can't use these views, I cant write on the EditText, I can't click the button; they're visible; but I can't use them.
And also; when I click or drag in the free space on the new layout, the Map will move, it's just like the map is still there. I hope that my problem is clear.
Here the code I am using:

Xml File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#E8E8E8">

            <!-- Champs de saisie pour effectuer la recherche:  -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >      

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Cacher"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cacher" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:onClick="onClickCacher"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CaptionRecherche"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Entrer l'emplacement que vous cherchez: "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Cacher"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Recherche"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Salle, Deparetement..."
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:maxLines="1" 
            android:layout_below="@id/CaptionRecherche"
            />
       </RelativeLayout>
                <!-- La map:  -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/MapLayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
protected static LinearLayout MapLayout;
    protected TranslateAnimation animationUp;
    protected RelativeLayout RLayout;

    public static ViewTreeObserver vto;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

RLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout);
        MapLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MapLayout);
        Toast.makeText(context, "MapLayout: "+MapLayout.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Solution found dans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn
        vto = RLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new GlobalLayoutListener(RLayout, context));
                MapLayout.startAnimation(GlobalLayoutListener.animationDown);
        RLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

GlobalLayoutListener:

```
public class GlobalLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    RelativeLayout layout;
    Context context;
    public static int LHeight;
    public static TranslateAnimation animationDown;

    public GlobalLayoutListener(RelativeLayout layout, Context context){
        this.layout = layout;
        this.context = context;

    }
    Animation.AnimationListener listener = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
        LHeight = height;
        animationDown = new TranslateAnimation(MainActivity.MapLayout.getX(), MainActivity.MapLayout.getY(), MainActivity.MapLayout.getY(), height);
        animationDown.setDuration(1000);
        animationDown.setFillAfter(true);
        Toast.makeText(context, "LayoutHeightttttttttt (Message dans the other classe ya baa ): "+LHeight, 3000).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is because you are not using property animation to animate the map.The animation you are using makes it look like the map has moved but actually it has not.PropertyAnimator on the other hand moves the whole object.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator

Comment: You are welcome.I hope you don't mind marking this answer as correct then. :)