# Android - When is my view complete drawn and visible on the display?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, view, activity-finish

My app shell read data from a file on the device.
I create the tables but they are not instantly shown (i create them in the onCreate() method).
Maybe you can give me a hint were i can start scraping my data from the web, because when i do it in my main activity it will jump over the first step to show my data from the database.

I am trying to get notified by my main activity when its completely drawn (when the user can see the UI).

I realized that this way:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener) [...]
```

is not working, because when this method is called i am not able to see my view on the device.
So i logged some variables in this method to get more information about this view:

```
log("isActivated: " + linearLayout.isActivated()); --> returned false
log("isEnabled: " + linearLayout.isEnabled()); --> returned true
log("isInTouchMode: " + linearLayout.isInTouchMode()); --> returned true
log("isShown: " + linearLayout.isShown()); --> returned true
```

I mentioned that the only variable which is not true, was view.isActivated().
Can you tell me whats the best way to wait for your application till everything its drawn (hopefully **not above API 11**).

Edit: some code if you wanna see

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Group> groups = null;
        String path = getFilesDir() + separator + STORAGE_FILE;
        File storageFile = new File(path);

        try {
            InternalGroupStorage storage = new InternalGroupStorage();
            if (storageFile.exists()) {
                log("Load groups from storage: " + path);
                groups = storage.loadGroupStorage(path);
                createGroupTables(groups);
                log("Tables created");
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            scrapeGroupsFromWeb();
            log("JSONException occured: groups going to be scraped from weg now.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void scrapeGroupsFromWeb() {
        try {
            GroupScraperTask task = new GroupScraperTask();
            List<Group> groups = task.execute("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H").get();

            if (groups == null) {
                return;
            }
            log("Groups were scraped.");
            InternalGroupStorage groupStorage = new InternalGroupStorage();
            String path = getFilesDir() + separator + STORAGE_FILE;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            groupStorage.saveGroupStorage(fos, groups);
            createGroupTables(groups);
            log("Tables created.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void createGroupTables(List<Group> groups) {
        GroupTable groupTable = new GroupTable();

        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 0, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableA));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 1, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableB));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 2, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableC));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 3, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableD));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 4, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableE));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 5, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableF));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 6, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableG));
        groupTable.createGroupTable(this, groups, 7, (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        log("resume");
        scrapeGroupsFromWeb();
    }
}
```

onResume(); is called before my tables are drawn!

edit2 added this in my onCreate():

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                int width = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
                log("draw?");
                scrapeGroupsFromWeb();

            }
        });
```

Its only drawn after my `scrapeGroupsFromWeb()` in my `onGlobalLayout()`

Comment: Why do you need to have your view visible to the user before starting anything else? The view exists on return from `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` whether it's visible or not. Even if it isn't visible, you can still access elements of that view and set their contents etc etc.

Comment: You are calling `scrapeGroupsFromWeb` in `onResume` and in `onCreate`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you tell when a layout has been drawn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)

Comment: @TyMarc I only call `scrapeGroupsFromWeb` in `onCreate` when there is a JSONException catched.

Comment: @loeschg I also tried that. When the `onGlobalLayout` is called my tables are created but not drawn.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does. But even if the `JSONException` is not called, you still call `createGroupTables` in `onCreate` and in `scrapeGroupsFromWeb`. That way, even if you don't have an exception, it will be called two times.

Comment: @TyMarc Between the time its called it should already be drawn one time, after i called it again it should be redrawn. I dont get the problem.

Comment: @unrated : You haven't answered my question. Why does the layout need to be visible to the user before you start using it?

Comment: @Squonk Sry, missed your comment. I want to load data from an internal database. Then i want to present my data in my app. After they are shown i want to refresh my data automatically from the web. I want to do that because the refreshing takes a while when the connection is bad.

Comment: @unrated : It seems you're fixating on something which may be a problem caused by another part of your code. As I said, the layout actually exists (in memory) after `setContentView(...)` returns even if it isn't visible to the user. You can access any part of the layout using `findViewById(...)` even if the user can't see the layout. The process of creation, starting, resuming is synchronous - you won't see anything until the `Activity` is resumed, i.e., running.

Comment: @unrated : I've just realised you are using the `get()` method of an `AsyncTask` - don't ever do this. The method is absolutely pointless and I have no idea why the Android devs added it to `AsyncTask`. It basically turns an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one. In other words it will block your UI thread which is why you're seeing the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Squonk Merry me! That was the problem <3

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is done by adding a ViewTreeObserver to the view. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/413254

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

Comment: I added this and i call my function ´scrapeGroupsFromWeb()` in there. But its only drawn after my ´scrapeGroupsFromWeb()` in my `onGlobalLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

@loeschg answer worked for me, but a little detail I want to add, to help the prospect answer seekers in the future:

- the "LinearLayout" in

  ```
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
  ```

works with all the layout there is I believe, I'm using FrameLayout myself.

- Get an "android:id=`@+id/your_id_here` in your corresponding xml file if you don't know how to findViewById.
- Do not get rid of `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);`unless you want to have this call back invoked everytime something happens to the layout.

Oh and SEO: layout, complete, finish, drawn, after, callback, listener