# Scale drawable in Android to support multiple screens

Tags: java, android, xml, scaling, screen-resolution

Currently I seek a solution to simple situation, which appeares to become tricky. I need 7 togglebuttons in android app, which are a simple black circles, but I need them to be in the row and fill parent (screen) horizontally. As a resource I use big .jpeg image of a circle. To make them fill all screens in the same mode, I put them into LinearLayout with

```
@android:layout_width = "fill_parent";
@android:layout_height = "wrap_content";
@android:weight="70";
```

Weight is 70, so each button received 10. The problem is that source image is too big, which unfortunately results in...this:

(because I dont have enough reputation for posting images, here is the link 
http://postimg.org/image/f8wvs5si1/ )

Sorry for small amount of code and this picture taken via phone, I do not have an internet access on the computer with eclipse and this project for some time. I tried of course to change layout_height on other possibilites, but it didnt work. I could put a weight sum also on the vertical position, but on different screens it wouldn't look same.
I also tried to change the height programmatically in onCreate method,

```
 buttonX.setHeight(buttonX.getWidth());
```

or do the same with a layout, but nothing helped

Perhaps the question is dumm, but I would be glad to hear some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to screen density variations. There are several things you can do to fix this:

1. Use different images for each density (but I'm assuming you're looking for another solution)
2. Use DisplayMetrics to get the actual width of the screen and then set width/height accordingly.
3. This code:

   buttonX.setHeight(buttonX.getWidth());

probably doesn't work because you are calling it before the layout is drawn, and therefore the width is not the drawn width. You can fix this using `ViewTreeObserver` like here:

[How can you tell when a layout has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)

4. Use an XML attribute like `scaleType="centerFit"` Personally, I find these confusing because `scaleType` attributes don't always seem to behave the same way to me. You might have to try different ones, but sometimes they come in handy if you need an XML only solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try 3 and 4, mostly 3 )
It seems also useful for similar custom objects

Comment: It seems that none works, but there is a possibility I use ViewTreeObserver incorrect. Firstly, the line of the code "this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);" returns me that layout can't be resolved or not a field (but it was layout.getViewTreeObserver().etc). Secondly, I have discovered that the values of height and width are not null only inside the method. I tried to implement this interface in my Activity class, but it was the same: a variable was not 0 in the method, but not elsewhere. And, finally, I could not set the button height

Comment: Finally! It worked! Thank you, I just had to use LayoutParams to set up my preferred height