# How to draw a layout inside layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-viewtreeobserver

I have aplication where after clicking on Statistics i call StatsFragment. StatsFragment uses fragment_stats xml layout that has there a TabLayout and CustomViewPager. However when i clicked on Statistics so my StatsFragment is called data are not drawn there. After i click on some tab data will be there.
Problem is with initial drawing. From [How can you tell when a layout has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn) i know i shall use somehow ViewTreeObserver but cant find the way where and how.

fragment_stats xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".StatsFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<!--android:elevation="6dp"-->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    />

<pv239.fi.muni.cz.moneymanager.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

</pv239.fi.muni.cz.moneymanager.CustomViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

tab_fragment xml file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewScreenStats">


        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/graph" />

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/stats"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/box"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:rowCount="5"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Starting balance: "
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/startBalanceLabel"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startBalanceLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/startBalance"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/startBalance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Ending balance: "
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/endBalanceLabel"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/startBalance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/endBalanceLabel"
                android:id="@+id/endBalance"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Incomes: "
                android:layout_below="@id/endBalanceLabel"
                android:id="@+id/incomeStats"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/recordPositiveValue"
                android:id="@+id/incomeSumStats"
                android:layout_below="@id/endBalance"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Expenses:"
                android:id="@+id/expenseStats"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/recordNegativeValue"
                android:id="@+id/expenseSumStats"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="+/- status:"
                android:id="@+id/actualStats"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/actualSumStats"
                android:textColor="@color/recordPositiveValue"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1" />
        </GridLayout>
        <!-- Income records -->

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box"
            android:layout_below="@id/stats"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/listViewIncomeStats"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

        <!-- Expenses records -->
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listViewIncomeStats"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/listViewExpences"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

StatsFragment java file:

```
public class StatsFragment extends Fragment  {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private ListView incomeListView;
private ListView expensesListView;

private OnStatsInteractionListener mListener;

public StatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment StatsFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static StatsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    StatsFragment fragment = new StatsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)         getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("7 days"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 month"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 year"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    final CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            //   TextView txt = (TextView) (adapter.getItem(tab.getPosition())).getView().findViewById(R.id.startMonthStats);

            processChanges((adapter.getItem(tab.getPosition())).getView(),tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onStatsInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnStatsInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onStatsInteraction(Uri uri);
}

private Date numbersToDate(int daysBack, int monthsBack, int yearsBack)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthsBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, yearsBack *(-1));
    return  cal.getTime();
}

public void processChanges(View tabView, int tabNum)
{
    int d =7;
    int m =0;
    int y =0;
    MMDatabaseHelper sloh = MMDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

    if (tabNum == 1)
    {
        d =0;
        m =1;
        y =0;
    }
    else if (tabNum == 2)
    {
        d =0;
        m =0;
        y =1;
    }
    createGraph(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setBalances(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setListValues(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);

}

private void setListValues(View tabView, int d, int m, int y,MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Creating incomes list
    incomeListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewIncomeStats);
    Cursor incomeRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter incomeAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), incomeRecords, 0);
    incomeListView.setAdapter(incomeAdapter);

    // Creating expenses list
    expensesListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewExpences);
    Cursor expensesRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter expensesAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), expensesRecords, 0);
    expensesListView.setAdapter(expensesAdapter);
}

private void setBalances(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    //Fetching Values of incomes and expenses and balances
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    TextView incSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.incomeSumStats);
    Integer helpInc = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal incValue = new BigDecimal(helpInc.toString());
    incSum.setText(format.format(incValue.abs().setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView expSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.expenseSumStats);
    Integer helpExp = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal expValue = new BigDecimal(helpExp.toString());
    expSum.setText(format.format(expValue.abs().setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView startBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.startBalance);
    BigDecimal startValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getStartingBal(numbersToDate(d,m,y)).toString());
    startBal.setText(format.format(startValue.abs().setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView endBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.endBalance);
    BigDecimal endValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getEndingBal().toString());
    endBal.setText(format.format(endValue.abs().setScale(2).doubleValue()));


    TextView actState = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.actualSumStats);
    actState.setText(format.format(new BigDecimal(helpInc + helpExp).setScale(2).doubleValue()));
}

private void createGraph(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Graph rendering section
    // Cursor graphCursor = sloh.getRecordsInRange(null,d,m,y);
    // graphCursor.moveToFirst();
    int days=0;
    if (d == 7) { days = d;}
    if (m == 1) { days = 28;}
    if (y == 1) { days = 365;}

    ArrayList numList = new ArrayList();
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] { });

    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    day.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    for(int i=days; i>0;i--) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-i);
        day.setTime(cal.getTime());
        Log.i("TIME",cal.getTime().toString());
        numList.add(sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime()));
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(day.getTime(),sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime())),true,days);
    }

    Log.i("Pole", numList.toString());

    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity()));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(4); // only 4 because of the space

    graph.addSeries(series);
}
}
```

Comment: <include> will simply past it there. However no data are shown. Its same result liek without it.

Comment: thanky you for clearing that out!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you're not doing the right things at the right time.
When the `onCreateView` of your fragment is called, you inflate the corresponding layout but do not set any value in there.

Simply swapping all the code you have in `onActivityCreated` into the `onCreateView` should do the trick, as follow :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("7 days"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 month"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 year"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


final CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager);
final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
processChanges((adapter.getItem(tab.getPosition())).getView(),tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
    });
return (layout);
}
```

EDIT : After having a second (and closer) look  at your code, the best idea would be to have fragments managing your tabs, so that you could put your logic in there (and place them in each tab). To do so :

Step 1 : Create a new fragment class for your pages

```
public abstract class PageFragment extends Fragment {
  private int pageNumber;
  public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page_number", page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return (fragment);
  }
  public PageFragment(){}
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
      pageNumber = getArguments().getInt("page_number");
    }
  }
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    //Get all the views you need for your page, using 
    //layout.findViewById();

    //Then you will need to call processChanges for that page
    processChanges(layout, pageNumber);
    return (layout);
  }
  //Also add here all the logic associated with processChanges
}
```

Step 2 will be to get references of your fragments in your StatsFragment, and add these fragments to your pager :

```
private PageFragment pageOne;
private PageFragment pageTwo;
private PageFragment pageThree;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
 pageOne = PageFragment.newInstance(0);
 pageTwo = PageFragment.newInstance(1);
 pageThree = PageFragment.newInstance(2);

 tabLayout.addFragment(pageOne, "7 days");
 tabLayout.addFragment(pageTwo, "1 month");
 tabLayout.addFragment(pageThree, "1 year");
 tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
}
```

Step 3 : You will finally need to have a custom pager adapter to hold the titles and the fragments of your pager :

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<>();

  public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
  }

  public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
      mFragments.add(fragment);
      mTitles.add(title);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return (mFragments.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return (mFragments.size());
  }

  @Override
  public String getPageTitle(int position) {
      return (mTitles.get(position));
  }
}
```

To use it, simply create it via (instead of your `PagerAdapter`)

```
final MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Comment: This will call  
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
in it. It stucks right on   
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

Comment: You're correct, see my edit : you don't need to call getView.findViewById since we get the view, simply call layout.findViewById

Comment: Now application is running but it didnt solved the problem.

Comment: Well the rest is somehow "normal" as the computing you're doing is located into the `processChange` function, which is only called in case of a tab changed. If you need it before, simply call it when you need it, such as before the line `return (layout);`, which is, when all your views are ready to be filled in with values

Comment: I tried to call processChanges(adapter.getItem(0).getView(),0); which shall point to the first tab on position 0 but it throws : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference. So on position 0 is null. I tried even position other positions but its still null.

Comment: I made an entire new edit with a completely different approach, to have a better structured code. Briefly, each page is now a fragment, so the logic for the data is in there. The StatsFragment is now simply a holder for the viewPager.

Comment: Seems nice. Only tabLayout.addFragment(pageOne, "7 days"); is not working cause it has no such function. If i remove second parameter there is still inconsistency in pageOne is PageFragment and is expected TabLayout.Tab

EDIT: aswell had to remove abstract cause cannot instantiate from abstract

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to provide you with a custom PagerAdapter to handle the fragments, see my Step3 now :)

Comment: Thank you very muchi I made some minor other changes and is fully functional now. I will update aswell my answer with working code. Thank you very much for help. Awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Nsimon i update current state. This solved problem with initial screen for me. Big thank to NSimon.

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mTitles.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (mFragments.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (mFragments.size());
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return (mTitles.get(position));
}
}
```

PageFragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
private int pageNumber;
public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page_number", page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return (fragment);
}
public PageFragment(){}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt("page_number");
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    //Get all the views you need for your page, using
    //layout.findViewById();

    //Then you will need to call processChanges for that page
    processChanges(layout, pageNumber);
    return (layout);
}

public void processChanges(View tabView, int tabNum)
{
    int d =7;
    int m =0;
    int y =0;
    MMDatabaseHelper sloh = MMDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

    if (tabNum == 1)
    {
        d =0;
        m =1;
        y =0;
    }
    else if (tabNum == 2)
    {
        d =0;
        m =0;
        y =1;
    }
    createGraph(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setBalances(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
    setListValues(tabView, d, m, y, sloh);
}

private void setListValues(View tabView, int d, int m, int y,MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Creating incomes list
    ListView incomeListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewIncomeStats);
    Cursor incomeRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter incomeAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), incomeRecords, 0);
    incomeListView.setAdapter(incomeAdapter);

    // Creating expenses list
    ListView expensesListView = (ListView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.listViewExpences);
    Cursor expensesRecords = sloh.getRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    RecordsDbToStatsAdapter expensesAdapter = new RecordsDbToStatsAdapter(this.getContext(), expensesRecords, 0);
    expensesListView.setAdapter(expensesAdapter);
}


private Date numbersToDate(int daysBack, int monthsBack, int yearsBack)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthsBack *(-1));
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, yearsBack *(-1));
    return  cal.getTime();
}

private void setBalances(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    //Fetching Values of incomes and expenses and balances
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    TextView startBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.startBalance);
    BigDecimal startValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getStartingBal(numbersToDate(d,m,y)).toString());
    startBal.setText(String.valueOf(startValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView endBal = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.endBalance);
    BigDecimal endValue = new BigDecimal(sloh.getEndingBal().toString());
    endBal.setText(String.valueOf(endValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView incSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.incomeSumStats);
    Integer helpInc = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange(">",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal incValue = new BigDecimal(helpInc.toString());
    incSum.setText(String.valueOf(incValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));

    TextView expSum = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.expenseSumStats);
    Integer helpExp = sloh.getSumRecordsInRange("<",d,m,y);
    BigDecimal expValue = new BigDecimal(helpExp.toString());
    expSum.setText(String.valueOf(expValue.setScale(2).doubleValue()));
}

private void createGraph(View tabView, int d, int m, int y, MMDatabaseHelper sloh) {
    // Graph rendering section
    // Cursor graphCursor = sloh.getRecordsInRange(null,d,m,y);
    // graphCursor.moveToFirst();
    int days=0;
    if (d == 7) { days = d;}
    if (m == 1) { days = 28;}
    if (y == 1) { days = 365;}

    ArrayList numList = new ArrayList();
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] { });

    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    day.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    for(int i=days; i>0;i--) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-i);
        day.setTime(cal.getTime());
        Log.i("TIME",cal.getTime().toString());
        numList.add(sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime()));
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(day.getTime(),sloh.getCurrentBalanceForOneDay(cal.getTime())),true,days);
    }

    Log.i("Pole", numList.toString());

    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity()));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(4); // only 4 because of the space

    graph.addSeries(series);
}

}
```

StatsFragment:

```
private PageFragment pageOne;
private PageFragment pageTwo;
private PageFragment pageThree;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    pageOne = PageFragment.newInstance(0);
    pageTwo = PageFragment.newInstance(1);
    pageThree = PageFragment.newInstance(2);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("7 days"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 month"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1 year"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(pageOne,"7 days");
    adapter.addFragment(pageTwo,"1 month");
    adapter.addFragment(pageThree,"1 year");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
    return layout;
}
```