# Stop animation from taking my view out of screen android

Tags: android, animation

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bounceBallButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Bounce Ball" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bounceBallImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/bounceBallButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ball" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my animation code to bounce my imageview:

```
Button bounceBallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bounceBallButton);
final ImageView bounceBallImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bounceBallImage);
bounceBallImage.clearAnimation();
TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, getDisplayHeight());
transAnim.setStartOffset(500);
transAnim.setDuration(3000);
transAnim.setFillAfter(true);
transAnim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());                
bounceBallImage.startAnimation(transAnim);
```

My problem is that the animation takes my imageview below my screen. I want it to hit at the bottom of my screen and bounce and not go below it.

Answer (score 0):

You animate `Y` position to `getDisplayHeight()`. Which means, that you tell the framework:

> animate this view's top `Y` position to the screen's bottom.

And framework does exactly what you say.

What you want to do is to animate to `getDisplayHeight() - bounceBallImage.getHeight()`. But as soon as you do that, you'll find out, that it gives you the same result. That's because `getHeight()` returns 0, and that's because your view's hasn't been drawn, hence it has not height.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/1083957) how to know the height of the view as soon as it is measured. You'd be using `getMeasuredHeight()` instead of `getHeight()`.

Comment: bounceBallImage.getHeight() and bounceBallImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); height = bounceBallImage.getMeasuredHeight(); Both returns the same value. and decreasing these from getDisplayHeight() is not resolving the issue.