# performClick not working when using spinner library

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have implemented this spinner in my app. I'm displaying a dialog and I have my spinner in that dialog. I want my spinner to open as the dialog comes up. I have tried performClick() event right after setAdapter() method but it doesn't seem to work.

My code looks like this:

```
final MaterialBetterSpinner selectBrandForSODRating = dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectBrandForSODspinner);

final ArrayList<Products> brandList = new ArrayList<Products>();
Cursor crsCheckSODData = database.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
if(crsCheckSODData.getCount() > 0){
  while (crsCheckSODData.moveToNext()) {
     //data...
     brandList.add(data);
  }
}

crsCheckSODData.close();

final ArrayAdapter<Products> SODBrandAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Products>(myView.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, brandList);
selectBrandForSODRating.setAdapter(SODBrandAdapter);
selectBrandForSODRating.performClick(); //this right here isnt working...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner, the code is overriding `onTouchEvent` [here](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/blob/master/library-material/src/main/java/com/weiwangcn/betterspinner/library/material/MaterialBetterSpinner.java#L62), but not overriding `onClick`. That's why `performClick` will not work.

You could simulate touch event instead to the view. Here's how:

```
int[] coords = new int[2];
selectBrandForSODRating.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
float x = (float) coords[0];
float y = (float) coords[1];

// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime1 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime1 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
MotionEvent motionEventDown = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime1, 
    eventTime1, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
selectBrandForSODRating.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventDown);

long downTime2 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime2 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
MotionEvent motionEventUp = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime2, 
    eventTime2, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
selectBrandForSODRating.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventUp);
```

You could also directly call the methods from [here](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/blob/master/library-material/src/main/java/com/weiwangcn/betterspinner/library/material/MaterialBetterSpinner.java#L78)

```
selectBrandForSODRating.requestFocus();
selectBrandForSODRating.showDropDown();
```

But I don't recommend it, because there is another boolean state, [isPopUp](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/blob/master/library-material/src/main/java/com/weiwangcn/betterspinner/library/material/MaterialBetterSpinner.java#L80), that has private access and you can't access.

Comment: @3iL you need to create both events, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: Thanks for the update it did work but the spinner list is appearing behind the dialog. Any idea why It is behaving that way?

Comment: your second suggestion is also working but with the same issue.

Comment: I just ran the code with a 1 sec interval and it worked

Comment: Can you confirm that the spinner list is in front of the dialog if you touch it by your finger?

Comment: Instead of 1 sec interval, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/3940133 better solution for your problem