# Why Does RecyclerView Update Without notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

It is common knowledge to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()` when you mutate an array that is being handled by a RecyclerView adapter in order to update the view and reflect the changes made. But I spun up a sample application in which neither are called when I add items to an array immediately after calling `.setAdapter()` in the same block, and the view updates! This behavior doesn't happen when I try to add items via a button's `onClickListener` or from a background thread (both require `notifyDataSetChanged` for the view to update).

What's going on here? Shouldn't adding items to the list immediately after calling `.setAdapter()` in the same block require something like `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

i.e.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        myList.add("a");
        myList.add("b");
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        myList.add("c"); // the recyclerView is updating and shows "c" here! why???

        findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myList.add("e"); // the recyclerView will NOT update here unless you call `notifyDataSetChanged`
            }
        });

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing an `ArrayList` to your `Adapter`, and you're adding elements in `onCreate`, that would be before the app has drawn your first frame.

There is a moment where you're able to add elements, because the adapter hasn't laid out the items.

And within your `onClick`, that would be after `onCreate` has finished, which means the `adapter` is already laid out.

You could try moving `add("c");` to `onPostCreate` or `onResume` and you may see similar result as your `onClick`.

Comment: do you happen to have a source or reference for when you mentioned "because the adapter hasn't laid out the items"?

Comment: @GrantPark No, I do not. It's just the Android lifecycle, and `onCreate` is before the actual layout is laid out. For example, if you tried to get your height/width of your `RecyclerView` in `onCreate`, it'd return 0. You can check out something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/3106174, which shows you can get a callback to when it's actually laid out.